# How can I remove .0 from 2017.0, 2018.0, 2019.0 etc..?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
data3['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data3['release date']).year

release date box office   admissions year
0 2014-07-30 135756879810 17615590 2014.0 
1 2019-01-23 139648179516 16264984 2019.0 
2 2017-12-20 115707014137 14411662 2017.0 
3 2014-12-17 110940529730 14263332 2014.0 
4 2019-04-24 122182694160 13934592 2019.0 

data3 = data3.astype(str)
data3 = [line.rstrip(.0) for line in data3]
```

I want to remove all '.0' from 'year' column.
I searched a lot but replace() is not working and rstrip() has error. 
To correct error, I changed the type of data3 to (str).. but still got error

How can I remove .0 from year column ?

Comment: I'm sorry it's quite difficult thank you I'll try

Comment: You are not selecting the data3[‘year’] column when your using .astype() and .rstrip().

Answer (score 1):

The results is in float: so

`df['column_name']= df['column_name'].astype(int)`

does the job *if there are no missing values* in `column_name`. If there are, then the dtype will be float, and therefore .0

If you want to overcome that then you have to replace NaN first: e.g:

`df['column_name']= df['column_name'].fillna(0.0).astype(int)`

The year 0 is for missing values.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
data3['year'] = data3['year'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the type of the date:

```
    type(data3.year.dt.year)
```

You'll see it's numpy.float64. You can cast floats to ints with a lambda function, and apply it across the column:

```
    data3["year"] = data3["year"].apply(lambda x: int(x))
```

Note: This will throw an error if you have NaN values in your date column, and you'll need to account for the missing data somehow.

Answer (score 0):

To remove .0 from years just you need to convert it into Integer data type as it is float.

```
a = 1990.0
a = int(a)
print(a)
```

Output Will be

```
1990
```

You can check data type by type()  funtion.

or use

```
 data3['year'].astype(int)
```

astype() will convert your data into integer data type